# What's the bad having 2 internet connections connected at the same time?

Tags: networking

I use home network for all PCs, but I also set laptop can connect to internet directly without network though all the connections are through the same broadband. 
The reason I allow independent connection for laptop is in case when home network lost(the hub is not stable, and I don't have time to buy it yet ), laptop can still connect.
I have some doubts here, -- How I know which connection the laptop is using? I guess the direct line is faster, but how I set the laptop to go through the direct connection?

Comment: Wouldnt you need to tell what operating system it is?  or did you just need to know which wire to remove?  What are the connections?  wireless? wired? What is the network through your referring to?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it. I use Windows xp pro. It's broadband connection. The network is my home network.

Comment: Only one broadband line, all PC connect to a hub and joined the same group.. ISP limit the hub to 2 PC but I have 4, So, there are 2 PCs can always go without network, and 2 PCs must go through network. It's not router, just a hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use something unix-ish and have the iproute2 package installed, you could just run `/sbin/ip -f inet route`. There will be a *default* entry, likely the top one. It should show which device is used as source when attempting to reach another host on the Internet, along with the address used as source. The other lines show more specialised routes accessed through other interfaces.

If you were referring to ipv6, you should type `inet6` rather than `inet`.

If you don't have iproute2 available, you could use `/sbin/route -A inet` for similar effect.

Comment: And the Windows equivalent is `route PRINT` or `netstat -r`. The one at the top is used first by default. In this case, the best would be `route PRINT 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks! @Bob route PRINT 0.0.0.0 got it. Both are active, with direct connection on top. Do you think 2 active connection may course speed slow down?

Comment: @Jenny: It won't, unless the connection drops on a regular bases and forces your to change the routing table everytime.  Then it may slow things down.